# trying to install pymssql on ubuntu 12.04 using pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, pip, pymssql

I am trying to install pymssql on ubuntu 12.04 using pip. This is the error I am getting. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am completely lost!

Tried googling this but unfortunately to no avail...

```
  Downloading pymssql-2.0.0b1-dev-20130403.tar.gz (2.8Mb): 2.8Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pymssql
    warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Utility'
    Compiling module Cython.Plex.Scanners ...
    Compiling module Cython.Plex.Actions ...
    Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Lexicon ...
    Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Scanning ...
    Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Parsing ...
    Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Visitor ...
    Compiling module Cython.Compiler.FlowControl ...
    Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Code ...
    Compiling module Cython.Runtime.refnanny ...

    Installed /home/radek/build/pymssql/Cython-0.19.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
    cc -c /tmp/clock_gettimeh7sDgX.c -o tmp/clock_gettimeh7sDgX.o
    cc tmp/clock_gettimeh7sDgX.o -lrt -o a.out

    warning: no files found matching 'win32/freetds.zip'
Installing collected packages: pymssql
  Running setup.py install for pymssql
    skipping '_mssql.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building '_mssql' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/radek/build/pymssql/freetds/nix_64/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.o -Wno-parentheses-equality -DMSDBLIB
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.o -L/home/radek/build/pymssql/freetds/nix_64/lib -lsybdb -lct -lrt -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lct
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/radek/build/pymssql/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-Et_P1_-record/install-record.txt:
    running install

running build

running build_ext

skipping '_mssql.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)

building '_mssql' extension

creating build

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/radek/build/pymssql/freetds/nix_64/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.o -Wno-parentheses-equality -DMSDBLIB

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.o -L/home/radek/build/pymssql/freetds/nix_64/lib -lsybdb -lct -lrt -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lct

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/radek/build/pymssql/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-Et_P1_-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
```

Comment: Just so this is searchable: Ubuntu 14.04 will throw "mssql.c:346:22: fatal error: sqlfront.h: No such file or directory". Installing freetds-dev fixes the issue as per the answer below.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Make sure you have the `python-dev` package installed (needed to compile packages with native bindings (thanks to @ravihemnani).

Then you'll need to install the FreeTDS development package (`freetds-dev`) before trying to install `pymssql` with pip:

```
$ sudo apt-get install freetds-dev
```

and then, in your *virtualenv* or wherever you wish to install it:

```
$ pip install pymssql
```

Comment: if pip doesn't work: sudo apt-get install python-pip will install pip

Comment: sudo apt-get install -y freetds-dev solves my issue. Thanks.

Comment: same issue in debian and apt-get install freetds-dev solved my problem too !

Comment: I needed `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include` too.

Comment: This also worked on my Raspberry Pi, however I had to install pymssql as root with `sudo pip3 install pymssql` because I got a PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/_mssql.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so'

Answer (score 15):

Apart from freetds-dev, you need to install python-dev as well as follow.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Or else, you will again face some error.

Comment: This comment is VITAL to make the accepted comment succeed! (At least in 14.04LTS) Thanks, Ravihemnani

Answer (score 3):

For those on OpenSuse (and related OSes):

```
zypper in freetds-devel
pip install pymssql
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac

```
brew install freetds@0.91
brew link --force freetds@0.91
pip install pymssql
```